# An inequality involving common polynomial divisors of maximal degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, divisibility, integral-domain

Let $R$ be a domain. For all $f,g\in R[X]$ non-zero, define
$$D(f,g):=\max\{\deg d:d\in R[X],d\mid f,g\}.$$
**Question:** For which $R$ does the inequality 
$$D(f,g)+D(f,h)\ge D(f,gh)$$ 
hold for all $f,g,h\in R[X]$ non-zero? In particular:

1. Is it enough for $R$ to be pre-Schreier?
2. Is it enough for Euclid's lemma (the general version, $a|bc$, $(a,b)=1$, then $a\mid c$) to hold in $R$?

What I know so far, is that the inequality holds for all $f,g,h\in R[X]$ non-zero if $R$ is a GCD domain.

Comment: Let me just say that I know the question asked here is not very clear from the title. I struggled to come up with a good one, and if anyone has a better title, feel free to edit.

Comment: The argument for pre-Schreier seems straight forward, what's giving you trouble? I don't know about 2.

Comment: For pre-Schreier, start with an argmax $d$ on the RHS, apply the condition to $d \mid gh$, and get a lower bound for an argmax on the LHS

Comment: @RghtHndSd So are you saying that if $R$ is pre-Schreier, $R[X]$ is too?